# I want to configure nginx server with multi applications (nodejs, django) in one domain

Tags: node.js, django, nginx, centos

I have nodejs app (techkids.vn) that run on port 8080 and Django application running on port 8000 of the same server. Then I want to map the Django application on domain techkids.vn/djangoapp. This is my current configuration on Nginx (default.config), but its not work

Code:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}

 location /djangoapp/ {
   proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
   proxy_set_header Host $host;
   proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
   }
```

Comment: Cool. What is your question?

Comment: when you say "not work" do you get an error, a blank page, does the machine explode, do you get stung by bees every time you hit refresh?

Comment: Sorry i forgot!!! The error  here is caused by all file in source code was error:
`socket.io.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`
 I think the problem maybe link file isn't exact ?